# Electric displacement of parallel plate capacitors

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

Suppose I have a parallel plate capacitor with surface charge density $\pm\sigma$. In between the capacitor is a sandwiched (linear) dielectric and say I'm interested in determining the electric displacement, $\mathbf{D}$. My textbook determines this by using Gauss's law where he draws a Gaussian cylinder: the top face of the cylinder lies in the capacitor and the bottom face lies within the dielectric. The author claims that then $$DA=\sigma A \Rightarrow D=\sigma$$ since the top face does not contribute anything. Is this because all of the free charge lies on the surface of this capacitor? This leads to me another question: why did he choose this particular arrangement of the Gaussian surface? Why didn't he choose a cylinder so that the top face is above the plate and the bottom face is within the dielectric? Also, why did we suddenly assume the capacitor plate has some finite width? All along we assumed an arbitrary thin plate. Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: The choice of Gaussian cylinder was to use the fact that the electric displacement within a plate which is made of a conductor is zero.

Comment: @Farcher It is a common issue among the students, so if you get some time, please elaborate the answer.

Comment: Could you please illaborate?